# Lua the __ipairs function implemented does not end the loop

Tags: lua, metatable

I made an empty table, and using `ipairs` to access it will call other functions, but I don't know how to end the loop, when the loop proceeds to the last element, it still continues

```
local arr = {}
arr = setmetatable(arr, {
    __len = function(tbl)
        return 5
    end,
    __index = function(tbl, index)
        return 1
    end,
    __ipairs = function(tbl)
        local function iter(array, index)
            index = index + 1
            local value = nil
            if index <= #array then
                value = 1
            end
            if nil ~= value then return index, value end
        end

        return iter, tbl, 0
    end
})
for _, v in ipairs(arr) do
    print(_, v)
end
```

[image]

Comment: I assume you meant `ipairs(arr)`. Double check ´GetTableValue´, does it return nil if the element does not exist?

Comment: @Luke100000 I updated the problem to check the index before doing the `GetTableValue` function to make sure it returns `nil` if it goes out of range, but it still doesn't work

Comment: Can you define "doesnt work"? What values do you receive when printing the index and value in the loop? Will it spam nils? I can run your example (with only the tbl/arr fix applied) on all common lua versions.

Comment: @Luke100000 When using `ipairs(arr)` to access values, the number of loops exceeds the length of arr

Comment: Yea but how do you notice. What are the out of bounds results of the iterator.

Comment: @Luke100000 I've updated a use case that can be run directly

Comment: Thanks! I have bad news. It still works. See this online proof for the output I see: http://tpcg.io/_UL6LVZ I receive 5 times a 1. What Lua version do you use, and in what environment?

Comment: @Luke100000 The version of lua is 5.4, I updated the image again

Comment: Ohh, I'm sorry, I assumed the online Lua would also be a 5.4. Yes, you example doesnt work on 5.4 because `__ipairs` has been removed. You need to use `pairs` and `__pairs` respectively. It gets stuck in a look because you also implemented __index, which returns a constant. I will validate my claims and post a proper answer soon.

Comment: @Luke100000 You are correct, `__ipairs` was deprecated in 5.3 and removed in 5.4. `ipairs` iterates using normal access (`table[n]`) until first `nil` is encountered. Since `__index` always returns `1`, it's never done. The solution is `pairs` _or_ fixing `__index`.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In Lua 5.3, the `__ipairs` metamethod has been deprecated, see https://www.lua.org/manual/5.3/manual.html#8.2

In Lua 5.4 it has been removed. That means, it will be ignored, and is only relying on `__index`, which returns a constant 1 and thus remains stuck.

A solution would be to use `pairs`:

```lua
local arr = {}
arr = setmetatable(arr, {
    __len = function(tbl)
        return 5
    end,
    __index = function(tbl, index)
        return 1
    end,
    __pairs = function(tbl)
        local function iter(array, index)
            index = index + 1
            local value = nil
            if index <= #array then
                value = 1
            end
            if nil ~= value then return index, value end
        end

        return iter, tbl, 0
    end
})
for _, v in pairs(arr) do
    print(_, v)
end
```

Answer (score 0):

I think the cleaner solution is to fix `__index` rather than switching to `pairs`; this allows you to trivially implement `__pairs` in terms of `ipairs`:

```lua
arr = setmetatable(arr, {
    __len = function() return 5 end,
    __index = function(self, index)
        return (index >= 1 and index <= #self and index % 1 == 0 and 1) or nil
    end,
    __pairs = function(self) return ipairs(self) end
})
```

You will then be able to use `arr` with `pairs` and `ipairs` *and* indexing as if it were a table of five ones:

```lua
$ lua
Lua 5.4.4  Copyright (C) 1994-2022 Lua.org, PUC-Rio
> arr = {}
> arr = setmetatable(arr, {
    __len = function() return 5 end,
    __index = function(self, index)
        return (index >= 1 and index <= #self and index % 1 == 0 and 1) or nil
    end,
    __pairs = function(self) return ipairs(self) end
})
> arr[42]
nil
> arr[1]
1
> for _, v in ipairs(arr) do print(v) end
1
1
1
1
1
> for _, v in pairs(arr) do print(v) end
1
1
1
1
1
```

---

That said, such a dummy table is usually dirty. The fact that you were able to swap `ipairs` with `pairs` suggests to me that you are able to refactor the code that works with this dummy table. In that case I'd suggest generalizing it to work with an *iterator* rather than expecting a *table*; you can then trivially write a `range` iterator that loops over five ones.